# SQL Allocate credit with datetime overlap

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm working on a type of bot detection system that helps me run some ML to identify this traffic.

Long story short, I have two tables:

1. One table contains all of the server log data (requests down to the second level) with a datetime column
2. One table that has a row for an exceptional event I have identified. (with a datetime column)

So I have two tables and want to do a join between them and sum up the server request column. It gets tricky since the exceptions can overlap.

Let's imagine that we have the table **Exceptions**:

```
Name       | Datetime          | LengthInMin
ExceptionA   01-01-18 08:00:00   5
ExceptionB   01-01-18 08:02:00   5
```

And the table **Log**:

```
Datetime           | Requests
01-01-18 08:00:01    50
01-01-18 08:00:03    100
01-01-18 08:00:04    350
01-01-18 08:00:06    100
```

In the simple case, Exception A can have all the requests to itself.
[image: simple]

In the more complicated case, multiple exceptions can share credit:
[image: overlap]

How do I go about doing this in SQL? I'm not quite sure where to start.

Comment: Are these tables essentially storing your `access_log` and `error_log`?

Comment: Kinda :) the exceptions table is one that stores some "flagged" time intervals. Then I must go to the access_log for more details to process further and do this weight allocation. I just don't know how to deal with the overlaps in SQL.

Comment: I was just going to say that unless the `access_log` has already been filtered, how do you know that every entry directly correlates to an exception, and wasn't actually a valid, successful request? But I'll give your problem some thought too.